# Nested loops and for each give me undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, loops

```js
const index = this.areas.findIndex(a => a.id === area.id);
if (index > -1) {
  this.areas.splice(index, 1);
  this.dashboardConfiguration.widgets.forEach(wAId => {
    const allWidgetByAreaId = wAId.widgets.filter(w => w.areaId === area.id);
    allWidgetByAreaId.forEach(w => {
      w.areaId = null;
    });
  });
}
```

Hello, Above is my code. I have (widgets which is WidgetAccess[]) and it contains  widgets[]. The problem is area.id is undefined so  I can't have w.areaId = null. Would you please help?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I am not having error but I need to have w.areaId == null when w => w.areaId === area.id but area.id  is undefined!

Comment: Can you provide data too